# error in installing package pleas help

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

When I try to install packages in the terminal it keep saying:

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 38055:
 invalid package name (may not be empty string)
libdvd-pkg: Package libdvdcss2-1.4.0-1 was removed, stop processing...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: This may be easier if your command was included, plus more of the output around the error was included.  Have you tried the obvious `sudo apt install -f` ?  (inc. version of Ubuntu)